# How to correctly install ipfs js to run on console

Tags: ipfs

I installed ipfs using the following command

```
sudo npm install ipfs --global
```

I am getting an error `ipfs:command not found` when i run in it node console.
what am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's something wrong with your $GOPATH, or you haven't added your $GOPATH's /bin to your $PATH. See the GOPATH section in this doc page: https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH

Comment: Why do I need GO for a node package?